# OVR_multiview2 in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

can we use gl_view_id in fragment shader with GL_OVR_multiview2 extension? Spec only says that we can use it for other vertex outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GL_OVR_multiview has this in the issues section:

> (6) Is ViewID visible at every pipeline stage?
>
> Resolved: To make integration simple for app developers, the intent is for ViewID to be visible as a built-in at each programmable pipeline stage.

So that settles that.

Only not really, because the [normative text of the specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/OVR/multiview.txt) doesn't make it clear that it is available in *any stage*, vertex shaders included. Notice that there is no declaration for `gl_ViewID_OVR` *anywhere* in the specification. So until [that gets cleared up](https://www.khronos.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1493), there's no way to know if it is even available in vertex shaders.